# Use properties to parameterize connection to Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I am trying to use Properties file to parameterize connection to Mongodb.

I have added this function:

```
public static Properties load(String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
  Properties properties = new Properties();

  FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
  try{
     properties.load(input);
     return properties;
  }
     finally{
     input.close();
  }

}
```

and use this code:

```
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/config.properties";
    Properties prop = load(path);

    //System.out.println("key: "+ prop.getProperty("MONGO_HOST"));


    try {
//m = new Mongo(config.MONGO_HOST, config.MONGO_PORT);
    m = new Mongo(prop.getProperty("MONGO_HOST"), config.MONGO_PORT);
this.db = m.getDB("cloud_datasource");
             db.authenticate(config.MONGO_USER, config.MONGO_PASS.toCharArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Can't connect to MongoDB");
             e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

In my config.properties: `MONGO_HOST="192.168.10.84"`

Problem: with this code, I have an error `java.net.UnknownHostException: "192.168.10.84"`
but if I am using the code:

```
m = new Mongo("192.168.10.84", config.MONGO_PORT);
```

it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (without quotes):

```
MONGO_HOST=192.168.10.84
```

Comment: Yes that's it ! I just made the test and it was OK.

Answer (score 0):

make sure what Tomasz said (no double quotes in prop file). then if it still doesn't work then maybe cast the prop.getProperty() to a String like this:

```
m = new Mongo((String)prop.getProperty("MONGO_HOST"), config.MONGO_PORT);
```

Comment: [Properties.getProperty()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)) already returns `String` so casting is unnecessary and won't even appear in bytecode after compilation - so this is basically a no-op.